# With C++20 facilities is there a nice way to do an "finally" operation?

Tags: c++, c++20

Clearly there are classic ways to do something when an object goes out of scope but I am curious if there's a better in C++20 to do something like the following?

```
    struct OutOfScopeOperation {
        OutOfScopeOperation() : {} 
        ~OutOfScopeOperation() {
            // Do something! We're out of scope
        }
    };
```

Comment: What feature of C++20 do you think changes things? The closest C++ has gotten to what you seem to be asking about is [`std::experimental::scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit) from TS3, but that wasn't implemented in C++20.

Comment: Technically you can do a 'finally' with C++98... Boost has been doing it for years. It becomes more elegant with C++14.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Go's `defer`](https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/12), so you can run arbitrary bits of code as a scope closes?

Comment: or [Boost scope exit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/scope_exit/tutorial.html)

Comment: I find *RAII* much more elegant. I remember Borland's compiler extension `try{} __finally{}` and removing it wherever I could.

Comment: You haven’t actually articulated a problem with existing utilities or suggested a problem you’re unable to solve with them. What, exactly, Is the issue you are having?

Comment: Nothing will ever make "finally"-style exception handling "nice".  With cleanup-in-a-destructor, you write the cleanup code once and it gets automatically reused for every instance of the object.  With "finally", you write the cleanup code over and over again with no reuse.